# sample OpenCL code for neural network for windows

Tags: opencl

I am searching for a  neural network sample code in `OpenCL`, that I might optimize using GPU kernels. Please help me as I am a beginner in `OpenCL`.

Comment: You may want to look at [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog).  It supports GPU operations, in some versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've started writing a deep convolutional neural network library for OpenCL at https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/tree/master . So far, it supports:

- convolutional layers
- max-pooling
- softmax
- random translations layer
- random patches layer
- normalization layer
- multinet (aka 'multi-column', per http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.2745.pdf )
- fully-connected

... running on the GPU, using OpenCL.  You can specify the network architecture on the commandline, like `100C5-MP2-100C5-MP2-100C4-MP2-300N-100N-6N`.

Edit: can get 99.55% test accuracy on MNIST now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into this **OpenCL enhanced version** of FANN library for fast neural networks.
I am sure it will need some optimization :-)
I also plan to optimize THIS lib.

**http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/2011/02/opencl-enhanced-version-of-fann/**